# Unable to iterate the linked list in C

Tags: c, loops, pointers, linked-list, iterator

I am trying to print all the members of a linked list. I am traversing the list and counting the duplicate copies of the integers in the list if any. But when I traverse the list again to check for duplicate copies, my ipNext points to null terminating my previous traverse loop.

Inserting data function:

```
void insertIP(bstNode *head, char user[], int ip){
    if(head != NULL){
        bstNode* startList = head;
        while ((startList) && (strcmp(startList->data, user) != 0) ){
            if(strcmp(user, startList->data)<0)
            {
                startList=startList->left; 
            }
            else if(strcmp(user, startList->data)>0)
            {
                startList=startList->left; 
            }
        }

        if (startList != NULL){

            IP* new = (IP*)malloc(sizeof(IP));
            new->ip = ip;

            //new->count = (new->count + 1);
            new->ipNext=NULL;

            IP* temp = startList->ipHead;
            startList->ipHead = new;
            new->ipNext = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Iteration function which looks for a specific data entry and count the occurences of it in the linked list if any.

```
bstNode* search(char* key, bstNode* root)
{
    int res;
    bstNode *leaf = root;
    if( leaf != NULL ) {
        res = strcmp(key, leaf->data);
        if( res < 0)
            search( key, leaf->left);
        else if( res > 0)
            search( key, leaf->right);
        else
        {
            printf("\n'%s' found!\n", key);

            //int count = 0;
            bstNode *temp = leaf;

            while (temp->ipHead != NULL) {

                int tempip = temp->ipHead->ip;
                int ipcount = 0;


                uint32_t ip = tempip;
                struct in_addr ip_addr;
                ip_addr.s_addr = ip;

                bstNode *cpy = leaf;
                ipcount = count(&cpy, tempip);

                //temp = leaf;

                printf("The IP address is %s\n C:%d\n", inet_ntoa(ip_addr), ipcount);

                temp->ipHead = temp->ipHead->ipNext;
            }
        }
    }
    else printf("\nNot in tree\n");
    return leaf;
}
```

Supporting function (This set the ipNext value to null which terminates the loop in search. Even though I am passing a copy of the pointer, I think that is my problem).

```
int count(bstNode** start, int item)
{
    bstNode* current = *start;

    int count = 0;
    while (current->ipHead->ipNext != NULL)
    {
        if (current->ipHead->ip == item)
        {
            count++;
        }
        current->ipHead = current->ipHead->ipNext;
    }
    return count;
}
```

The data structure decleration:

```
typedef struct ip{
    int ip;
    struct ip *ipNext;
}IP;

typedef struct bstNode
{
    char data[32];
    struct bstNode* left;
    struct bstNode* right;
    IP *ipHead; 
}bstNode;
```

BST insert function:

```
bstNode *insert(bstNode *root, char *word, int ip)
{

    bstNode *node = root; 

    if(node==NULL){
        node= malloc(sizeof(bstNode));
        //IP* ipNode=malloc(sizeof(IP));
        strcpy(node->data, word);
        node->left=NULL;
        node->right=NULL;
        insertIP(node, word, ip);
    }
    else{
        if(strcmp(word, node->data)<0)
            node->left=insert(node->left, word, ip);
        else if(strcmp(word, node->data)>0)
            node->right=insert(node->right, word,ip);
        else if(strcmp(word, node->data) == 0) {
            insertIP(node, word, ip);
        }
    }


    return node;
    }
```

I appreciate everyones help!

Comment: `current->ipHead = current->ipHead->ipNext` - that's a *really* bad idea for a function that should be read-only walking a linked list and counting nodes. Use a temp pointer; not the list head with overwrites. Passing a `const` single indirection pointer to this function (which is all it should really require, so...) would have caught this mistake at compile time. Unrelated, I *strongly* suggest not naming local variables the same name as the function they're contained in.

Comment: Are you trying to do a binary search tree or a sorted linked list, if its binary search tree you are not setting right side nodes in insertion

Comment: @Pras It looks to be a binary search tree whose nodes contain linked list chains of IP records.

Comment: Btw, the same problem is with `temp->ipHead = temp->ipHead->ipNext;` in your search function. You may want to review your text/curriculum reference on pointers. It seems you think that making a copy of a pointer means you can modify what it points to without repercussion. In reality, all it means is you now have *two* pointers you can/will modify data through.

Comment: @WhozCraig Right..apparently bst is by user, Anon_Singh in insertion function you should take right subtree here "else if(strcmp(user, startList->data)>0){startList=startList->left;}"

Comment: @WhozCraig  thanks for pointing out the mistakes How can I update the pointer without changing the initial root pointer, do I need to implement double pointer and setting each with an address of the previous one?

Comment: I have added the bst Insert function in case I messed up that too..

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, here is your problem:

```
    while ((startList) && (strcmp(startList->data, user) != 0) ){
        if(strcmp(user, startList->data)<0)
        {
            startList=startList->left; 
        }
        else if(strcmp(user, startList->data)>0)
        {
            startList=startList->left; 
        }
    }
```

You are taking the left path in both cases. I wouldn't post this as an answer (since it is already answered in the comments by Pras, but when I see this kind of non-optimized code, it bothers me: You may call the strcmp() function several times with the same data and the result will always be the same. strcmp() may be a costly operation if long strings are compared and besides you are doing this inside of a tree, so this operation could be performed A LOT of times. So why don't you assign the result in a variable the first time and then test the result, not call the strcmp() again. Like:

```
    int result;

    while (startList && (result = strcmp(startList->data, user)) ) {
        if (result < 0)
        {
            startList = startList->left; 
        }
        else if (result > 0)
        {
            startList = startList->right; 
        }
    }
```

Actually the second if is not needed, you may use a simple else because the test for zero is done in the condition of the while statement, so apparently if the result is not < 0, it will be > 0 for sure.